# Attempting to build several files from one file only

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I Have a csv file with three columns: name, ID, type. I have to pass a program throw each ID and generate a file with the name in the column name of the xlsx file. This is the code I thought, but now I don't really know the way to write each file with the name of the first column in a xlsx file.

```
list_ID = []
list_name = []
f = open('file_ID.csv', 'r')
data_type = f.readlines()
for line in data_type[1:]:
    split_line = line.split('\n')
    split_column = line.split(',')
    Column_ID = split_column[1]
    list_ID.append(Column_ID)
    Column_name = split_column[0]
    list_name.append(Column_name)
new_list_name=[]
for item in list_name:
    item2=item.replace(' ', '_')
    new_list_name.append(item2)
new_list_name
current_file_index = 0
for item in list_ID:
    for type in new_list_name:
        current_file_index += 1
        with open(f'{type}.txt', 'w') as f:
            check_output("blastdbcmd -db nt_v5 -taxids " + item + " -out " + type, shell=True)´
```

f.write("%s\n" % type)

File example:
[![Name ID  Type
Dog 1   Var
Cat 2   Var
Red 4   Var
Blue    5   Var][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPxeI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPxeI.png)

I'm working in python.

I edited the code, however with this way, the code only does the first element of the python list.

Comment: You mention an `xlsx` file but your example is opening a 'csv' file.

Comment: Initially I did it as xlsx but now i'm using csv